# How do I temporarily disable Chrome notifications?

Tags: google-chrome

I know how to completely disable all notifications from all websites using Chrome settings but I would like to do so for a fixed amount of time only (I am presenting something from my laptop). How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just web notifications, or all Chrome notifications in general? `Settings>Content Settings>Notifications` will allow you to turn off all notifications from sites, but that doesn't block extension notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem (Tinder date inbound for a house visit). Installed this extension ("Mute Notifications"):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-notifications/bmjdeaihnngnnnaldgakphcaanioohgn

Comment: Permission request doesn't look ok: https://puu.sh/DEvif/5e959cfb1e.png Although, it can be Chrome mis-design.